How to divide a Word doc into two Horizontal rows (1:3), such that I can have a text and its translation
There are many solutions to have 2 columns sidd by side for such a thing, and making the boundaries invisible. But I'm working on translating and having purport on a Text, so I need to divide the doc into 2 horizontal halves, with the ratio 1:3.
The main text flows only in 1/4th part of the page, and the translation and commentary/purport is beneath it. How do I design my Word such that I'm able to make such a Layout?
Please suggest any other application where this possible.

To do this in Word, its cumbersum, but possible. To do it easy, use Microsoft Publisher. Its basically Word, but with sections build in so you can easily put 3 columns on a page, add an image and make all the words go around it etc.

I need rows, not columns. I'll try using Microsoft Publisher. Thanks.

The columns was just an example.

There is no fully automated option for this in Word. But I think the easiest method would be the following:

Create a new style and open the "Modify" dialog
In the bottom left of the dialog window, go to "Format" > "Paragraph"
In the new window, switch to the "Line and page break" tab
Check the box which says "Page break above"
Save the style

Now, always use this style for the first paragraph of your original language. When you apply that style, it will automatically push the paragraph onto the next page.
You can also use this style in combination with a table. So, if you for example create a table with 10 rows and apply that style to every odd-numbered row, then each row will start on a new page. You can then give each odd-numbered row a desired height (e.g. 5cm) and each even-numbered row a different height (e.g. 10cm).
All of that is not ideal of course, but it is the best work-around I can think of.

Thanks a lot. This works!

@RishiGoswami glad to hear that! In case your question is solved, please make sure to mark the answer as your solution so that it isn't considered open anymore.
